# Products page screen option adjust number of products per page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I did something stupid. I am using Wordpress with Woocommerce plugin. On the admin side Products page I adjusted the amount of products to show under screen options to 999 per page, when it obviously should be a much smaller number like 20. This now causes the site to time out when I navigate to the products page. Is there a way to change that setting somehow another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste the below code in functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'reset_screen_options');
function reset_screen_options() {
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'edit_product_per_page', 20 );
}
```

You should remove this code after you get back control of your admin.

Comment: You are welcome. Just make sure you remove this code or otherwise your screen options will always default to `20`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed as the "Show Screen Options" disappeared from the products page on my WooCommerce installation!